# Is it possible to make an Android app and a Cordova app communicate via Wi-Fi Direct?

Tags: java, android, cordova, server, phonegap

I have to develop two applications: the first (the Cordova one) has to connect with the Android application and has to send multiple choice questions. The second (the Android one) must select the correct option and send the response. Since both devices are on the move and i have to find an alternative solution to the classic server that acts as a bridge, i was thinking of using Wi-Fi Direct.

So i wanted to ask if it is possible to make these two applications communicate through this standard even if they use two different programming technologies.
I have doubts about it because all the examples i find simply use the same app on different devices.

Finally, is there a plugin that enables the use of Wi-Fi Direct on Cordova?

Comment: Yes. That is possible. For all client-servers combinations it does not matter in which language they are written.

Comment: `through this protocol ` You did not mention a protocol but the used protocol should be the same.

Comment: A thousand thanks!
Yes, you are right, I did not mention any protocols, I was wrong to write

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.